# Win 2003 Server copy/paste problem

Tags: windows-server-2003

We're running Win 2003 server R2.  Every few weeks, I find that the Paste command in My Computer is no longer available. A reboot fixes it.  Does anyone have any knowledge of a better fix for this?

Comment: Is this when logged in locally? or via remote desktop?

Comment: I'm logged in locally

Answer (score 3):

If you're accessing the server through **remote desktop Connection**, follow these steps to re-launch communication with the terminal server's clipboard:

- Use Task Manager to kill the rdpclip.exe process
- Go to File>"New task (Run...), and type "rdpclip.exe" to restart it

No need to reboot server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to kill and restart explorer.exe?

Comment: I didn't try killing it with task manager, but closing it and restarting doesn't work.

Comment: Kill all instances of explorer.exe, then run it from task manager.

Comment: OK, I'll try that next time it happens.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Paste command on the Edit Menu greyed out, or completely missing?
Greyed out means that Explorer doesn't think that anything is on the clipboard that can be pasted.  Missing completely means that something has messed up the menu structure.

Can you paste using the keyboard (CTRL-V)?

Comment: Paste is missing and the keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this bug very well under Citrix and/or some RDP-Sessions , sometimes Ctrl-Insert as a replacement to Ctrl-C works and Shift-Insert as Ctrl-V.
Is there anybody who can explain this behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for this hint:
    * Use Task Manager to kill the rdpclip.exe process
    * Go to File>"New task (Run...), and type "rdpclip.exe" to restart it

but should i do that on my lokal machine or on the remotely administered server?