# Windows 7 Remote Desktop with Windows 2003 Unable to Copy/Paste Files

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, remote-desktop, clipboard, clipboard-sharing

I am attempting to copy/paste files between Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003 across a Remote Desktop connection (in the same domain, if it matters), but I am unable to successfully do so.

I have followed [instructions](http://cutecomputer.wordpress.com/2007/01/03/howto-copy-paste-between-local-and-remote-desktop/) to enable clipboard sharing on the Windows Server 2003 machine by enabling the Network DDE, Network DDE DSDM, and ClipBook Windows services; also, I have ensured that the "Clipboard" option on the "Local Resources" tab of Windows RDP client is checked, but this does not appear to be doing the trick. The the remote desktop has been rebooted and the clipboard sharing services started without any errors.

Is there something I'm missing?

*This is similar to at least [one other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/25935/win-2003-server-copy-paste-problem) here, but I was unable to find a solution that worked.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, clip-board sharing does not extend to files just to text blocks. So it is possible to copy paragraphs between your host computer and the RDP session, just not copy and paste files. This is because the clip-board does not store files, per se, it just stores data.

Comment: I believe you're right. In order to transfer files between the two computers the OP will need to configure drive redirection.

Comment: This appears to be the case. I have just confirmed that I am able to copy raw text without any problems. Thanks!